# how to use strip in conjunction with split-dwarf?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb, debug-symbols

I am currently trying to use the `--gsplit-dwarf` `gcc` flag in order to automatically create and separate debug symbols from build libraries/executables. [More info on DWARF Obj files](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission). However, what I have observed is that `split-dwarf` still leaves a lot of unnecessary information in the remaining `.o` file. What I would like to do is use `strip` to remove that info but still have it be compatible for debugging using the `.dwo`/`.dwp` files; however, it seems that this does not work. I want to strip the release executables for space savings and for further obfuscation, and was hoping `split-dwarf` would allow me to do so.

[Additional reference](https://www.productive-cpp.com/improving-cpp-builds-with-split-dwarf/)

Example app `app.cpp`

```
 
int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  std::cout << "Split DWARF test" << std::endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

```
g++ -c -gsplit-dwarf app.cpp -o app_dwarf.o
```

Linking:

```
g++ app_dwarf.o -o app_dwarf -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--gdb-index
```

Examine the build artifact:

```
readelf -wi app_dwarf
Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0x30 (32-bit)
   Version:       4
   Abbrev Offset: 0x0
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <c>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x8da
    <14>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x9c
    <1c>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0
    <20>   DW_AT_GNU_dwo_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x0): app_dwarf.dwo
    <24>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0xe): /home/ross/Desktop/dwarf_test
    <28>   DW_AT_GNU_pubnames: 1
    <28>   DW_AT_GNU_addr_base: 0x0
    <2c>   DW_AT_GNU_dwo_id  : 0xdf705add23e14a0b
```

Can see it references the `dwo`... this also works in GDB and does not work when I remove the `dwo` file. However, if I look at the symbol table for the build artifact (the executable), the full symbol table is still there.

If I strip the executable, the table is removed and the size is reduced, but it also strips away the `debug_info` that references the `dwo` file.

Also separately, shouldn't the symbol table be included in the `dwo` file?

Hoping some direction can be provided here that will allow me to capture all of the debug info outside of the artifact itself to be kept for debugging at a later time.

The alternate way to do this would be a multi stage approach where we do something like:

```
g++ -g -o app_dwarf app.cpp 
objcopy --only-keep-debug app_dwarf app_dwarf.debug
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=app_dwarf.debug app_dwarf
strip --strip-unneeded app_dwarf
```

But would need to divide that up into compile and link steps so that build times and resources are affected less. I thought that was the whole point of the single `gsplit-dwarf` flag, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I strip the executable, the table is removed and the size is reduced, but it also strips away the debug_info that references the dwo file.

Correct.

The right way is to keep the *unstripped* copy of the executable and the `.dwp` file, while distributing the stripped copy to end-users.

> I thought that was the whole point of the single gsplit-dwarf flag, though.

No.

The motivation is explained [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission). To quote: "By splitting the debug information into two parts at compile time -- one part that remains in the .o file and another part that is written to a parallel .dwo ("DWARF object") file -- we can reduce the total size of the object files processed by the linker."

If the total size of object files processed by the linker isn't a problem for you (it rarely is for binaries under 1 GiB), then you don't really *need* fission (though it may still speed up your link a bit).